# Moving divs issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress page and I have this page where I need to get 15 pictures with text beneath them in 5 rows by three. I've done that, but now I need them to move one under another when resizing. It worked all well enough until I set the div for the pictures& text to be 30% wide.

Here's my code

```
<div class="wrapper-ostale-storitve">
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><a href="#"><img  width="300" height="207" /></a></div>
<div><a style="color: #000;" href="#">Picture A</a></div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><img  width="300" height="207" /></div>
<div>PIcture B</div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><img  width="300" height="207" /></div>
<div>Picture C</div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><img  width="300" height="207" /></div>
<div>Picture D</div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><img   width="300" height="207" /></div>
<div>Picture E</div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><img  width="300" height="207" /></div>
<div>Picture F</div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><img  width="300" height="207" /></div>
<div>Picture G</div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
<div><img  width="300" height="207" /></div>
<div>Picture H</div>
</div>
<div class="item-ostale-storitve">
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle of my coding.

https://jsfiddle.net/nzdoLzkw/

I might also add that I write this code directly in a new page in wordpress, I'm not creating a new template. So it will be easier for the owner of the page to change text & Pictures later.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do they have to be in specific order when the screen size is smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplest solution is using @media rule for different screen sizes. 
Here is example [https://jsfiddle.net/barbocc/nzdoLzkw/1](https://jsfiddle.net/barbocc/nzdoLzkw/1/)

```
.wrapper-ostale-storitve {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*make sure the wrapper has no dimension*/
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-ostale-storitve {
  width: 30%;
  height: 295px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
}

@media (max-width: 955px) {
  .item-ostale-storitve {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! For some reason i thought using @media would be more work. Guess not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved with bootstrap grid system. You can design several grid columns depending on the screen size. In that case you will need your pictures to have class img-responsive inside your div and div has a class col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 and etc..
If you cannot use bootstrap, then you can create your own @media rule for different screen sizes